# Categorical x continuous variable interaction in regression?

Tags: regression, interaction, categorical-encoding, mixed-type-data

I have a sample containing two subgroups and I would like to measure the relationship between two continuous variables across the entire group and check if there's an interaction with subgroup.

First, I just did a correlation but to include the interaction I guess I need to do a regression. So I have one continuous variable y as the outcome and one categorical variable (subgroup) and one continuous variable x as independents (along with two other variables I want to control for).

I think I should include the variables in the model along with the subgroup multiplied with variablle x to look at the interaction, but that would make variable x 0 for everyone in one of the subgroups which doesn't sound right. Can anyone tell me how to do this? (preferably in SPSS)

I also tried downloading PROCESS to SPSS but I'm not sure this gives me the test I want.

Comment: You’re right that you multiple by zero. Can you figure out how to interpret the regression parameters in that case?